# ElasticSearch - Match all search tokens in one or any fields in any order

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to write an elasticsearch (v7.17) query that returns all documents where all tokens in my search term match in one or any number of fields in any order.

I can do this per field, using a `multi_match` query with the operator `and`, but I want to do it for any number of fields, for example if there are 3 fields: `text1`, `text2` and `number1` and they are filled for two documents as such:

text1: 'Car',
text2: 'Audi',
number1: 'A6'

text1: 'Car Audi',
text2: ''
number1: 'Q7',

I want to find all two when I search "Car Audi", but only the first when I search "Car Audi A6" and none when I search "Car Audi A8".

How can I accomplish this without all just writing them into the same field (which I neither want nor can because they partly have different analyzers in the mapping)?

It's important to note that the mapping is a little complex and the fields have different analyzers so that the search token "Audi" in the field `text` will match also "Audi-123" for example while in the field number1 that's not the case.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive same using `multi_match` query only. here, you need to set `operator` value as `and` and `type` value as `cross_fields`. Please see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) documentation.

**Query:**

```json
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Car Audi A6",
      "fields": [
        "text1",
        "text2",
        "number1"
      ],
      "type": "cross_fields", 
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx, i too was able to figure it out eventually, my real problem was, the different fields had different search analyzers, so I needed to merge it all together in one search analyzer that fitted all my needs, then the above query worked just fine.

Comment: What if I only want to get only "Car Audi" or "Audi Car" and nothing else, what should be the query?

Comment: it will be the same query. just pass two words and field name in which you want to search.